# Я еду на автобусе

Tags: синтаксис

Я еду на автобусе.
В данном предложении **"на автобусе"** является обстоятельством образа действия?

Answer (score 1):

> Я еду на автобусе. В данном предложении **"на автобусе"** является
>   обстоятельством образа действия?

Я бы сказал -- **обстоятельственным дополнением** (термин Бабайцевой). Возможны вопросы и *ехал **как?*** (вопрос к обстоятельству образа действия) и *ехал **на чём?*** (вопрос к дополнению).